# Self-signed certificate verification not throwing SignatureException in Android

Tags: java, android, exception, ssl, x509certificate

In the following piece of code for an Android app, the server is presenting a self-signed certificate to connecting Android client. That is, I have signed the server's certificate with my own CA. This certificate is to be verified using the CA's public key, which is obtained from a file called *trust_store_ca* placed in */raw*. The problem is that if i use a different certificate (signed with a different CA, i.e.), the verification step does not throw a corresponding SignatureException. I have tested the code in NetBeans and **it does** throw the above-mentioned exception. However, in AndroidStudio **IT DOES NOT**. What might the problem be?

```
KeyStore ts = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
InputStream trustin = v.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.trust_store_ca);
ts.load(trustin, "MyKey".toCharArray());
// Create own trustmanager with self-signed cert.
final TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.
    getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
//tmf.init((KeyStore) null);
tmf.init(ts);
trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();

CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
InputStream cA_certificate = v.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ca_certif);
final X509Certificate caCertificate = (X509Certificate)cf
    .generateCertificate(cA_certificate);
// Check server certificate is valid
final X509TrustManager origTrustmanager = (X509TrustManager)trustManagers[0];

wrappedTrustManagers = new TrustManager[]{
                                    new X509TrustManager() {
    @Override
    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                                            return origTrustmanager.getAcceptedIssuers();
                                        }
    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {//Not used}

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) 
throws CertificateException{
    if (certs == null || certs.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
"checkServerTrusted: null or zero-length certificate chain");
    }
    if (authType == null || authType.length() == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
"checkServerTrusted: null or zero-length authentication type");
    }

// This does not work in Android, at least from me in JB...
//
// try { 
//      certs[0].verify(caCertificate.getPublicKey(), "BC");
//      Log.i(TAG,"Pubkey for caCertificate: "+ caCertificate.getPublicKey());
//      } catch (CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | 
//           NoSuchProviderException | InvalidKeyException | SignatureException e)
//            {Log.i(TAG,"Certificate verification exception" + e);}
//

// Do signature verification by decrypting it and comparing to expected
// value (01FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.....FFFFFF003021300906052B0E03021A05 000414... etc)

byte[] signature = certs[0].getSignature();   // signature in server's certif.
BigInteger exp = new BigInteger("010001",16); // 65537 as usual
BigInteger decrypt_sign = new BigInteger(1, signature).modPow(exp, ca_pubkey.getModulus());
System.out.println("Signature after decryption: " +decrypt_sign);
```

Edit: I am overriding the verification process because it's not detecting fake certificates. See my code edition, now just remains to check decrypted value against expected.

See:

http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html

for excellent explanation.

Also, thks to all who helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

It may have to do with the fact that you're eating (catching and not re-throwing) a bunch of exceptions that could be thrown by `certs[0].verify`

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned before, the code runs OK outside Android environment (NetBeans in my case), actually catching the SignatureException and printing to console. Do you still think I should modify that part of the code? What do you suggest? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A lot of the crypto libraries are different on Android - remember that this is a different environment from straight-up Java. Due to this, it's very possible that a different exception is being thrown, in a different place, when you're on Android. You should handle all exceptions appropriately, never 'eat' them.

Comment: @user4646718 Is there a line with "Certificate verification exception" in your log on android?

Comment: @vlp No, there´s not, that's the problem. Anyway, had to move on with this so I finally decided to compute it manually (see Edit).